# Amixer shows line out is plugged in but Pulse Audio thinks it's unplugged?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pulseaudio

Running Ubuntu 16.04.  Audio suddenly stopped working and now Pulseaudio doesn't think my line out is plugged in even though it is, and the kernel recognizes this as I can see by `amixer contents`.

Comment: Please edit queston with the output of `amixer contents` that makes you think the kernel "recognizes it" - the status of the jack plugs doesn't show up in any mixer settings I know of. As for selecting line out, make sure in "configuration" tab of `pavucontrol` that your card uses the right profile, then try to select "Line Out" in the "output" tab. If this doesn't work, please describe what you see in `pavucontrol`.